# Creating distribution curves with specific moments

Tags: r, plot, statistics, distribution

Is there a way to create a distribution curve given the 1st through 4th moments (mean, variance or standard deviation, skewness, and kurtosis)? Here is a small table of the descriptive statistics. The fifth variable has stronger positive skew and larger kurtosis than the rest, and leads me to believe a non-normal distribution may need to be used.

```
dput(summarystats_factors)
structure(list(ERVALUEY = c(1.21178722715092, 8.4400515531338, 
0.226004674926861, 3.89328347004421), ERVOLY = c(0.590757887612924, 
7.48697754999463, 0.295973723450469, 3.31326615805655), ERQUALY = c(1.59367031426668, 
4.57371901763411, 0.601172123904339, 3.89080479205755), ERMOMTY = c(3.09719686678745, 
7.01446175391253, 0.260638252621096, 3.28326189430607), ERSIZEY = c(1.69935727981412, 
6.1917295410928, 1.24021163316834, 6.23493767854042), Moment = structure(c("Mean", 
"Standard Deviation", "Skewness", "Kurtosis"), .Dim = c(4L, 1L
))), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

[image: Summary Stats Table]

Comment: Just as an FYI - there are multiple calculation definitions for moments so be sure whatever calculation was used matches the algorithm to recreate the distribution.

Comment: See this post for how to do it with discrete distributions. To make them continuous, you can add normally distributed noise. https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/483215

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `curve` with `PearsonDS::dpearson`. Note, that the `moments=` argument expects exactly the order *mean, variance, skewness, kurtosis*, so that the rows of the data must be ordered correspondingly (as is the case in your example data).

```
FUN <- function(d, xlim, ylim, lab=colnames(d), main='Theoretical Distributions') {
  s <- seq(d)
  lapply(s, \(i) {
    curve(PearsonDS::dpearson(x, moments=d[, i]), col=i + 1, xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim, 
          add=ifelse(i == 1, FALSE, TRUE), ylab='y', main=main)
  })
  legend('topright', col=s + 1, lty=1, legend=lab, cex=.8, bty='n')
}

FUN(dat[-6], xlim=c(-2, 10), ylim=c(-.01, .2))
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(ERVALUEY = c(1.21178722715092, 8.4400515531338, 
0.226004674926861, 3.89328347004421), ERVOLY = c(0.590757887612924, 
7.48697754999463, 0.295973723450469, 3.31326615805655), ERQUALY = c(1.59367031426668, 
4.57371901763411, 0.601172123904339, 3.89080479205755), ERMOMTY = c(3.09719686678745, 
7.01446175391253, 0.260638252621096, 3.28326189430607), ERSIZEY = c(1.69935727981412, 
6.1917295410928, 1.24021163316834, 6.23493767854042), Moment = structure(c("Mean", 
"Standard Deviation", "Skewness", "Kurtosis"), .Dim = c(4L, 1L
))), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hi, can you please explain your syntax more?

Comment: @Koalaconomist Could you be more specific on what is not clear to you?

Comment: What is d, i, and dat?

Comment: @MacroChair `d` is the function argument for the data `dat` that you find at the bottom of the answer. `i` is the argument of the anonymous function used in `lapply`, where we loop through the column indices. Does that help?

Comment: Yep, got it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you know how I can make the chart interactive to select which data variable to display?

Comment: @MacroChair Cool! You may look into [shiny](https://shiny.rstudio.com/), which is often used for such problems.

Answer (score 1):

Use the PearsonDS package, the pearson0 family creates "normal" distributions matching specified moments, but other options are available.